# Get array of event listeners

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

How can I get the array of event listensers that I have specified in the EventServiceProvider?

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\PaymentWasCompleted' => [
        'App\Listeners\GenerateInvoice',
    ]
];
```

Is there a "laravel" way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the Laravel way would be this:

```
app()->getProvider(\App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class)->listens();
```

If you changed the the default application namespace `App` to something else you have to change the statement accordingly